# Allow unprivileged LXC container to shutdown the host

Tags: kvm, qemu, shutdown, lxc, libvirt

I am running a KVM-QEMU VM inside an unprivileged LXC container. The customer requested that when a user shuts down the VM, the entire host shuts down.
I am using a libvirt hook to shutdown the LXC container:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 == "myvm" && $2 == "release" && $3 == "end" ]]; then
  poweroff
fi
```

I know I can use LXC's post-stop hook to run `sudo poweroff` at the host level but that would mean I'd have to allow a non-root user to shutdown the system without root password (by editing the sudoers file) which is not desirable.
I'd like to only allow the VM (or root) to shutdown the host if possible. If not, I'd like to allow the root user of the LXC container to shutdown the host.
How can I do that?

Comment: is the VM run as a particular user? (e.g. with `sudo qemu ...`)   if so, then that VM uid **only** could be allowed to run a script via sudo which runs `poweroff`.   Other users, those allowed to start the VM, are ony allowed to sudo the script that runs the VM, but not the script that runs poweroff.

Comment: BTW, whichever way you do this you WILL be allowing users who can start the VM to poweroff the system whenever they want.  All they have to do is start the VM and then exit from it.   This is a non-technical problem that should be solved by non-technical means (e.g. workplace policy with consequences for abusing the privilege).

Comment: @cas The VM is run as the root user of the container. I have no idea how to discover the UID of that user though. Another problem is that `poweroff` inside a LXC container shuts down the the container and not the host so I have no idea how to trigger that kind of behavior.